# How to get release notes from Semantic Release output using grep command

Tags: sed

I am trying to automate the release of software using semantic-release. Everything is working fine. I run this command `npx semantic-release --no-ci --dry-run` and get the following output in the terminal

```
...some other output

[1:01:55 pm] [semantic-release] › ⚠  Skip v0.1.1 tag creation in dry-run mode
[1:01:55 pm] [semantic-release] › ✔  Published release 0.1.1 on default channel
[1:01:55 pm] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Release note for version 0.1.1:
## 0.1.1 (2021-01-24)

### Bug Fixes

    * ravgeet is fixing things (92797f6)
    * removed unwanted files (bdcc9ff)
    * this is another fix (dbef2fd)
```

Now I need to get the release notes from the output

```
## 0.1.1 (2021-01-24)

### Bug Fixes

    * ravgeet is fixing things (92797f6)
    * removed unwanted files (bdcc9ff)
    * this is another fix (dbef2fd)
```

How can I do so using grep command or any other means?

Comment: With GNU sed: `| sed '/^##/,$!d'`?

Comment: Genius! How do you find the solution for this? I would love to learn this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed.

```
| sed -n '/^##/,$p'
```

> `-n`: Do not output anything unless it is explicitly stated (here with command `p`)

> `x,yp`: You can replace `x` and `y` with a regex (here: `/^##/`), a line number or a special character like `$`. `$` matches here last line in input.

> `/^##/`: regex for lines starting with two `#`

> `p` output sed's pattern space (current line).

---

`| sed '/^##/,$!d'`is a more compact notation. I translate `!d` with don't delete.

---

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)